# Preenchendo objetos Flash com cores sólidas e texturas

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Sou programdor Java há um tempo e agora estou criando uma espécie de livro de colorir em Flash baseado [nesse video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFbHFjqUqnU).

Hoje existe uma paleta de cores, ao clicar na cor e depois no desenho aquela parte recebe a cor escolhida usando o código:

```
 on(release){
   fillcolor=(0xFF0000) 
 }
```

[image: funcionamento atual]

Porém, como fazer o preenchimento através de uma textura? Eu preciso que ao invés de cores na paleta exista texturas e funcione da mesma maneira:

[image: funcionamento desejado]

Comment: Olá Dexter, 
Talvez uma outra abordagem que pode ser feita é adicionar ao objeto (acredito que um movieclip) um objeto (movieclip) dentro dele, este objeto pode ter o tamanho da tela, assim não haverá necessidade de colocar mais de um ou de redimencionar.

Uma forma de pensar é assim, ter uma variavel que armazena o valor da paleta (Qual a cor ou textura selecionada) este valor pode ser uma referencia a um movieclip.

Quando o evento release for ativado ele usa esta variavel e adiciona o objeto referido nela como único filho da forma que deseja pintar, por exemplo a tromba do elefante.

Comment: Isso deve dar a você o efeito desejado, e pode ser feito usando programação, contudo os objetos devem existir em sua biblioteca para que possam ser referenciados no AS.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginBitmapFill()

Comment: Não foi solicitado palpite, mas pelo "bem da web" sugeriria você ir pro universo do HTML, SVG, JS e CSS para fazer isso (ou usar alguma tecnologia mais robusta se for para desktop), pois o Flash está se tornando cada vez mais inconveniente com suas falhas de segurança e atualizações constantes (e agora com as tentativas de empurrar um navegador junto da instalação), e já não é mais "levinho" como era antes.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução bem simples para isso é:

Você ter um movieclip onde, em cada frame vc coloque uma textura diferente e o seu botão terá um evento que exiba o frame com a textura desejada:

Exemplo:

```
on(release){
    obj.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Nesse caso ***obj*** seria o nome dado ao seu movieclipe e ***2*** seria o frame a ser exibido.
*Obs:* não esqueca de colocar um stop(); na action do seu primeiro frame para não cair em looping o seu movieclip

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro de tudo (*e um conselho particular meu*) é você fazer este tipo de programação em  [ActionScript 3.0](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/), levando em consideração a praticidade no tratamento dos cliques na tela, já que o AS3 é [orientado à eventos](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fca.html), e possivelmente você estará mais familiarizado.

Seguindo a lógica do [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFbHFjqUqnU) em questão, preparei uma classe singela, que realiza as duas operações, tanto preenchimentos com cores sólidas `GraphicsSolidFill` como texturas bitmap `GraphicsBitmapFill`.

**Entendendo o preenchimento de objetos**

Todo e qualquer desenho que você realiza com preenchimentos, possui um objeto chamado `Shape` ([ref.](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Shape.html)). Neste objeto, uma propriedade chamada `graphics` ([ref.](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html)) controla as formas e linhas do seu "desenho", o que significa que você pode mudar qualquer propriedade do seu objeto.

> Este desenho nada mais é do que uma imagem em **Desenho Vetorial**. O que significa que a medição da mesma não é em Pixels, mas sim em Coordenadas Matemáticas. [Ref](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desenho_vetorial).

Vamos utilizar exatamente este objeto para tratar todas as modificações dos nossos movieclips.

**Respondendo a pergunta**

1. Faça um desenho no palco e cada parte do seu desenho converta-a em um `MovieClip`. *(Assim como no vídeo. É importante instanciá-los. Ex.: braco_mc, perna_mc, cabeca_mc... 'Supondo que seja um boneco.')*
2. Criaremos nossa função, vamos chamá-la de `fillTo();` que recebe um `MovieClip` e um objeto, seja `Bitmap` ou cor hexadecimal `uint`:

   ```
   var colortransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform(); //Criamos o objeto que aplica a transformação de cores no nosso desenho;
   var shapeGD:Vector.<IGraphicsData>; //Objeto vetor que contém os dados da nossa imagem
   var newGD:Vector.<IGraphicsData>; //Irá contém os novos dados do nosso desenho

   function fillTo(mc:MovieClip, obj:*):void {

       var shape:Shape = (mc.getChildAt(0) as Shape); //Recupera o desenho dentro do movieclip

       shapeGD = shape.graphics.readGraphicsData(); //Recupera os dados do nosso objeto Shape (curvas e linhas)
       newGD       = new Vector.<IGraphicsData>;

       //Para cada objeto dentro do nossos objeto vetor, recuperamos apenas a propriedades de linhas e curvas, deixando de lado as de preenchimento
       shapeGD.forEach(function(it:*, i:int, vec:Vector.<IGraphicsData>):void {
           if(!(it is GraphicsBitmapFill) && !(it is GraphicsGradientFill) && !(it is GraphicsSolidFill)) {
               newGD.push(it); //Adicionar somente as propriedades citadas
           }
       });

       //Verificamos se a propriedade passada é um Bitmap ou cor hexadecimao uint
       if(obj is Bitmap) {

           //Recupera o bitmap (no caso a textura)
           var bitmapData:BitmapData = (obj as Bitmap).bitmapData;

           //Objeto responsável por adicionar o preenchimento em bitmap ao nosso desenho
           var graphicsbitmap:GraphicsBitmapFill = new GraphicsBitmapFill(bitmapData);
           newGD.push(graphicsbitmap); //Puxa este objeto para nosso vetor

           //Adiciona as novas propriedades ao nosso desenho
           shape.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmapData, null, true, true);
           shape.graphics.drawGraphicsData(newGD);

       }
       else if(obj is uint) {

           //O procedimento é o mesmo, mas o objeto é diferente
           //aplicamos apenas a cor sólida ao nosso objeto
           var graphicscolor:GraphicsSolidFill = new GraphicsSolidFill(obj);
           newGD.push(graphicscolor);

           shape.graphics.beginFill(obj);
           shape.graphics.drawGraphicsData(newGD);

       }

      }
   ```
3. Para realizar o preenchimento aos nossos movieclips, basta você chamar a função assim:

   ```
   fillTo(perna_mc, 0xFF0000); //Pintando a perna de vermelho
   fillTo(perna_mc, textura_bitmap); //Pintando a perna com a textura em bitmap
   ```

Fiz uma classe chamada [Filler](http://abner.xyz/libraries/xyz/abner/display/Filler.as), para simplificar o tutorial.

Comment: Algumas informações que citei podem estar distorcidas. Caso estejam, peço que me informem, por favor! Havia um tempo que tinha visto esta pergunta no SOpt, infelizmente pela falta de tempo não pude pesquisar sobre a mesma.. :)